# iPython multiprocessing.pool: работает в Ubuntu, зависает на Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, anaconda, pool

Добрый день,

есть код для анализа текстовой информации, используется модуль pool из multiprocessing. 
На системе под Ubuntu (14.04, Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook) все работает великолепно, все 8 ядер загружаются, вопросов нет.

При запуске того же кода под Win10 (аналогично Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook, 12 ядер) ячейка в тетрадке подсвечивается (*), вроде как работает, но все ядра процессора пустые, процесс туда не идет, не завершается и не выпадает в ошибку.

Гуглил, то что нашел не помогает, if *main* и т.д. не помогает, воркэраундов не нашел. Можно сделать так, чтобы это работало винде?

_________Код_для_примера___________________

```
def get_word_distance(questions):
    q1, q2 = questions.split('_split_tag_')

    q1, q2 = tokenize(q1), tokenize(q2)

    return caluclate_simhash_distance(q1, q2)


pool = Pool(processes=8)
train['tokenize_distance'] = pool.map(get_word_distance, train['questions'])
```

Comment: Спасибо! а можете, пожалуйста, логику пояснить? преобразование в лист меняет логику работы pool? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
pool.map(get_word_distance, train['questions'])
```

замените на

```
list(pool.map(get_word_distance, train['questions']))
```

Дело в том что map возвращает ленивый итератор который создает потоки только тогда когда вам необходим их результат. Преобразования результата в список активирует весь итератор.

Comment: Сделали, но, увы, результат такой же(